# How to pass object argument to PlusDomains.Circles.list in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-plus

Recently was enabled Google + Domains API For Apps Script, I have explored some options and it seems is going to work, but in the specific case of PlusdDomains.Circles.list I don't know how to pass the second argument what is an object, I can not obtain several fields in the response, this is my code.

```
function getProfile() {
var userId = 'me';
var post = { maxResults: 2, fields:"title"};
var profile = PlusDomains.Circles.list(userId, post);

Logger.log('all: %s', JSON.stringify(profile));
}
```

this is the output,`all: {"title":"Google+ List of Circles"}`
if I try to get another field I don't know if this is correct, I put this:

```
var post = { maxResults: 2, fields:["title", "items"]};
```

but I get the same result:`all: {"title":"Google+ List of Circles"}`
If I try to get the result value for items, I get undefined. I don't how to pass the object correctly or if this is a bug in the Apps Script, somebody has idea??

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get this working too. From the public [google+ domain api docs](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/list) it looks that the fields property expects a string with field names comma separated, i.e.

```
var post = { maxResults: 2, fields:"title,items"};
```

I don't seem to get the items populated (all the properties are undefined) in my google apps script. But when I use the API explorer "try it" console with OAuth2 enabled for scopes https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/list and https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/list I do see the items populated, so I'm thinking there may be an issue with my scripts authorization scopes or a bug in the google apps google+ domain service.

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion of comma separated and I get the correct response, I have content in title and in items, still does not work for you??

Comment: Ty, since u were able to get it, I tried again, my issue is that I was trying "for (circle in circles.items)" but switching it to "for(var i = 0; i < circles.totalItems; i++) { Logger.log(circles.items[i].displayName;) }" is now working.

Comment: Could you please show me your code? for me what you want is working right now, at first glance I can see that you have a semicolon inside the Logger.log, that is wrong, but I don't know what else could you have wrong.